# Approximate n grade Bezier through cubic and/or quadratic Bezier curves

Tags: math, bezier, quadratic, cubic

I'm trying to draw a 6 grade (start point, 4 control points, end point) Bezier curve but the API offers me only cubic and quadratic curves methods.

Is there a way to split or approximate the 6 (or n) grade curve ONLY through cubic or quadratic ?

---

[Edit]
After some struggle I decided to write the library myself. Take a look here [How to draw n grade Bézier curve with Canvas API](http://diagramo.com/docs/html5-tutorials/how-to-draw-n-grade-bezier-curve-with-canvas-api.php)

Comment: I think you should ask this on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ Ishtar Thanks, did that here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92246/aproximate-n-grade-bezier-through-cubic-and-or-quadratic-bezier-curves

Comment: I wouldn't want to necro but on the site where you wrote the library yourself, you mentioned at the end of the article you were going to address even distribution of points. Have you written that article?

Comment: @Experimentators Nope, that article never came. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

Generally no. I would suggest creating your own Bezier curve method for 6 points (use wiki). And then use lines to draw the curve.

Comment: The reason I would have liked to use quad and cubic is that they are very fast and sometimes even hardware accelerated.

Comment: True, but if the API does not support them, there is not much to do. You really can not do a god approximate with quad or cube curves. There might be some fast way with shaders though.

Comment: It seems that I can use a BSpline line and then cut it in Bezier curves...so in the end I got a better shape but using Bezier cubic curves :)